# PHP : Getting image by removing all classes, ids ..ect from source

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a image in database stored in this format

```
 $link = this is my photo <img data-liked='0' data-reblogged='0' data-attachment-id="299971" data-medium-file="http://my.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/img_6697.png?w=394" width="73" height="130" src="http://my.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/img_6697.png?w=73&#038;h=130" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="IMG_6697" />, school photo;
```

i was wondring if this is possible to just get output

```
 this is my photo <img src="http://my.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/img_6697.png?w=73&#038;h=130" />, school photo
```

Just image source nothing else ...

I have tryed this and got image url but i need above result

```
$str = preg_replace('#<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].+/>#i', "$1", $link);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('#<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?\/>#i', "<img src=\"$1\" />", $link);
echo $str;
```

You might want to keep the alt:

```
$str = preg_replace('#<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?alt="(.*?)".*?\/>#i', "<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"$2\" />", $link);
echo $str;
```